# Should we add this post to the tour?

Tags: discussion, new-users, tour

In the [EL&U 2022 election chat](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/533/27581), it came up that new users need guidance. Many see this problem. I see something similar here on Hermeneutics.SE. New users need more guidance in the beginning.

Signup should help people to know what to expect. We have a [tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour), yet many new users are knowledgeable people who seem to be under the impression that common social media style comments can be bona fide Answers. We should make sure they know that *before*, not after the fact.

Should the tour include this post or a short quote from it?

Redaction:

---

## [What are we looking for in answers?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-we-looking-for-in-answers)

SE sites are primarily places for experts. Non experts are welcome in so far as they have an interest in becoming experts.

- Answers should show their work. This serves both as a way to verify their quality and as a way for people new to the field to learn.
- The take away value from answers should be seeing hermeneutical knowledge put into practice against the text. This includes seeing a particular hermeneutical approach take shape through the early stages of exegesis. The historical background of the author and audience, the original languages and the process of putting these pieces together should be the primary focus of what an answer conveys, not a doctrinal conclusion.
- Answers should stop short of prescribing a contemporary application. Doing so may be part of exegesis, but it is the far end of the spectrum away from the end we focus on.
- Answers will differ considerably based on hermeneutical principles applied, the theological presuppositions behind those choices, the breadth of knowledge in history, language and culture, etc. Having several diverse answers to each question should be something we prize.
- Answers must start from the specific text raised in the question and only draw on other sources/points as specifically relevant to interpret the original text.

Comment: I don't think we have space to add all that into the tour, unless you mean in the paragraph at the very top. But I think it's too long for that.

Comment: @curiousdannii Can we take anything from this to help?

Comment: We could definitely rework the initial description, but probably shouldn't make it much longer. Actually the links are broken now so we really should edit it! We could also edit the ticks and crosses boxes.

Comment: My Question here, then, is just to try to use this as a kind of framework for what you just describe. Leave it for me to do it when I get a chance. I should have the practice.

Comment: The most basic conditions should be informed to the new comers. It should warn that social media type opinions, remarks are not allowed here. Join only for serious academic posts. A precise description of a strictly descriptive nature, (non-judgmental) of the site should be explained. First Q/As should not be accepted directly, but sent to mods for approval and feedback, only after that a user should be allowed to post directly. This will save time of everyone checking the first answers.

Comment: @Michael16 *social media type opinions*... brilliant wording. Brilliant. Thank you.